# Checking the values of a dictionary against a string being read in externally

Tags: c#, string, dictionary

I've created a dictionary like so:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> myValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Then in my start method I'm filling out my dictionary like so:

```
void Start()
{
    myValues.Add("device one", "11111111111111");
}
```

And what I'm trying to do is check the value that I've created in my dictionary, in the above example it would be the `1111111111111`, against a string value that is being read in remotely. The check I'm doing is this:

```
void Update () 
{
    // Spawn a model based on the signal the ipad has recievied.
    if( myValues["device one"] == outputContent.text)
    {
        Instantiate(model1, new Vector3(-2.5f, 3.0f,0), Quaternion.identity);
    }       
}
```

The message is getting parsed from a wrapper class that takes information from native ipad stuff and passes it direct to unity. The method for getting the message is this:

```
private void AppendString(string message) 
{
    outputContent.text += "\n" + message;
}
```

Now, the thing is, the message getting passed works. When I run my code, the screen gets filled with the information I want. But when I try to check the values I've stored against the ones getting sent in, nothing happens.

How I got my initial hard coded value was by first reading them in from the AppendString method. And I've double checked them to make sure I've got the correct information down.

Can someone please tell me if I'm comparing the values held within my dictionary, to those being read in, is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of 'suspicious' spots.

Here, you add `\n`, are you sure that's included in the dictionary's value?

```
outputContent.text += "\n" + message;
```

Also, make sure you compare the strings properly. It may even be a capitalization problem, something that's bitten me many times. Try for instance:

```
if(String.Equals(myValues["device one"], outputContent.text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 0):

better replace following line

```
 if( myValues["device one"] == outputContent.text)
```

with:

```
 if( myValues["device one"].Equals(outputContent.text))
```