# Checking the values of a long string from a specific point

Tags: c#, ios, string, unity-game-engine

[This is a follow on from my last question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730915/checking-the-values-of-a-dictionary-against-a-string-being-read-in-externally/19731298?noredirect=1#19731298)

The string I am trying to compare comes through as follows:

```
Discovered Peripherial: <CBPeripheral: 0x39b8b50 identifier = DEEE65FB-FF1F-A6A9-4C3C-5784F41B0D39, Name = "rawr", state = connecting>
```

What I'm trying to do is check the identifier number to that which I'm storing in my program. To do that, I have done the following:

```
private void AppendString(string message) 
{
    message.Substring(message.Length-77, message.Length);
    outputContent.text += "\n" + message;
}
```

The \n is in there because I'm reading in 6 different devices and they all generate the above line. So I needed something to make it easier to read.

Then in my update function I am checking to see if they are similar like so:

```
if(String.Equals(myValues["UUID"], outputContent.text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    Instantiate(model1, new Vector3(-2.5f, 3.0f,0), Quaternion.identity);
}
```

However when I run this on my iPad, xCode generates the following message:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex + length > this.length
Parameter name: length
```

Which I'm guessing means I have miscounted the amount of characters I need to count back from in the substring.

My question is this:

Is there a better way in which I can compare my stored value with that of a specific part of a really long string or have I done something silly in my code which is generating that error?

This is a Unity project which I'm building onto an iPad and makes use of some functionality I can't replicate on a mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code i observed that you are calling Substring() method but not getting/saving its result into some variable .

```
message.Substring(message.Length-77, message.Length);
```

as string is an immutable which can not be modified.
hence when you call the Substring() method it cuts the required text and returns, which you have to save it on some variable to proceed further.
as below:

replace your function AppendString() as below :

```
private void AppendString(string message) 
{
   message= message.Substring(message.Length-77, message.Length);
    outputContent.text += "\n" + message;
}
```